# rvest error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") while reading a list in read_html

Tags: r, rvest

I've been scraping with rvest below on a webpage with multiple pages via lappy however I have come up with an error:
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list"

Not exactly sure how to fix it:

```
url <-'https://www.bunnings.com.au/products/bathroom-plumbing/plumbing/pipe-fittings/push-fit-pipe-fittings?L0=products&L1=bathroom-plumbing&L2=plumbing&L3=pipe-fittings&L4=push-fit-pipe-fittings&pageSize=36&page=1'

get_last_page <- function(html){
  
  pages_data <- html %>% 
    html_nodes('.MuiPaginationItem-sizeLarge') %>% 
    html_text()                   
  
  pages_data[(length(pages_data)-1)] %>%            
    unname() %>%                                     
    as.numeric()                                     
}

first_page <- read_html(url)
(latest_page_number <- get_last_page(first_page))

list_of_pages <- str_c(url, '?page=', 1:latest_page_number)

bun <- list_of_pages %>%
  lapply(read_html)
  data.frame(  
  paint = bun %>% html_nodes(".product-title") %>% html_text(), 
  price = bun %>% html_nodes(".price-medium-size p") %>% html_text()
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the output in one dataframe with `map_df` -

```
library(rvest)

result <- list_of_pages %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~{
    bun <- .x %>% read_html
    data.frame(paint = bun %>% html_nodes(".product-title") %>% html_text(), 
              price = bun %>% html_nodes(".price-medium-size p") %>% html_text())
    }, .id = 'id')

result
```

The `id` column shows from which link the data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bun` object is a list. That's what is returned from `lapply`. You cant pass a list to `html_nodes`. You probably want to apply over that list as well. Maybe `sapply` will work better in this case

```
dd <- data.frame(  
  paint = sapply(bun, . %>% html_nodes(".product-title") %>% html_text()), 
  price = sapply(bun, . %>% html_nodes(".price-medium-size p") %>% html_text())
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to edit the output a bit better as the items are in columns A, C and D with the prices in columns E, F and G?